# A new contact should be added to the top or to the bottom of the contact list?

Tags: lists, ios

If you have a contact list, and add a contact to that list, where should the icon of the new contact be added: to the top or the bottom of the list?

The contact list does not follow an exact order, its just data.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend sorting by *something*.

If it's just data - order by date added/edited from the latest on top to the last in the bottom. In this case, obviously, add it to the top.

**But really, my point is** - 
set some kind of default sorting and follow it. Date added/edited makes the most sense for me personally.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest allowing some sort of filtering, whether it be by most recently added, alphabetical, reverse, etc. Sort alphabetically starting with numbers.

If no filtering, put most recently added contact to the top of the list, state that there are the most recent (via heading title) and append a "Date added" to each contact. Regardless, for a better experience there should be some sort of way to both search and filter through any contact list that has dozens if not hundreds of contacts.